# Kendo UI / MVC - Getting a Menu item to open in a Tab page instead of calling Action, using onclick?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI menu:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name("menu")
                .Items(menu =>
                {
                    menu.Add().Text("About").Action("Index", "Home");
}))
```

Instead of loading the new page with an Action I want to call a javascript function onclick. How can I do this? Should I use the HtmlAttributes property?

Additionally, I'm using the moonlight theme which has white menu item text for non-actions and orange text for action menu items. For my menu item which will call the javascript function how would I keep this as orange text? By setting a style, or is there another way?

My sample code is on http://www.eeedee.com if I haven't explained myself well enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="menuItem1">Menu Item 1</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menu").kendoMenu({
            select: menuItemSelect,
            theme: "Moonlight"
        });
    });

    function menuItemSelect(e){
        alert(e.item.id);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can work with `andrewdudek84` answer(That way is really great).

There is two more solution (The hacking way):

**Solution 1**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
    .Name("menu")
    .Items(menu =>
    {
        menu.Add().Text("About").Url("javascript:void(0)")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { 
            @class= "helloWorld"
        });
}))
<script>
$('.helloWorld').click(function(){
    //put your code here
});
</script>
```

**Solution 2**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
    .Name("menu")
    .Items(menu =>
    {
        menu.Add().Text("About").Action("Index", "Home")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { 
            @class= "helloWorld"
        });
}))

<script>
$('.helloWorld').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the default action of your click.
    //put your code here    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why the `Url("javascript:void(0)")` as well as the `$('.helloWorld').click`. Can't you call a function in the JavaScript url?

Comment: You can call JavaScript function though URL simply like this: <a href="javascript: alert('Hello World')">Click Me</a>


javascript:void(0) just to make  sure Browser "Do not reload current page and do nothing".

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "LinkHtmlAttributes" to, um, add attributes to the generated link:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name("menu")
                .Items(menu =>
                {
                    menu.Add()
                        .Text("About")
                        .Action("Index", "Home")
                        .LinkHtmlAttributes(new { id = "myLink", onclick = "return OnMyLinkClick();" });
                }))
```

Comment: Yes! `.LinkHtmlAttributes(new { target = "_blank" });`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic, but for anyone looking to call an action method from the menu, but have the target page open in a new tab...

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
.Name("menu")
.Items(menu =>
{
    menu.Add()
        .Text("About")
        .Action("Index", "Home")
        .LinkHtmlAttributes(new { target = "_blank" });
}))
```